# Is it possible to check the z factor of a hillshade in the layer properties in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, parameters, hillshade, shaded-relief

I'm working with QGIS 3.18 and I want to compare the visual performance of different hillshade layers. For one that I already have I wanted to chek the building parameters, specially the z-factor but also the azimut, light height, etc. I thought I would find it under the info tab in the layer properties, but it looks that either I don't know where to look or that info is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's just a display method of an elevation file, and the layer properties just describes the elevation file (not the hillshade).

Even if you produce the hillshade using `gdaldem`, the resulting TIF file will not retain the parameters used to create it.

The best option may be to **rename** the layer with the parameters you used to create it.

Answer (score 3):

Z-Faktor can be found in the layer styling panel of the raster. Set the layer style to `Hillshade`. There, you also find other settings as azimut, light height etc:

[image]